# import or include playbooks in ansible version 2.3

Tags: ansible

I am trying to restart a service and want to import stop.yml and start.yml in restart.yml. So when I call restart.yml, it will call the stop.yml and start.yml. It works for me when I tested in my VM which was running in ansible 2.4

```
restart.yml
---
import_playbook.yml: stop.yml
import_playbook.yml: start.yml
```

the same is not working in version 2.3 in another environment. Is there a simply way in ansible version 2.3.

This works for me.

```
 cat restart.yml
---
- name: RestartPlay
  hosts: nodes
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "Restarting the service"

- include: stop.yml
- include: start.yml
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You're indenting is wrong, as it should be:

```yaml
---
- name: RestartPlay
  hosts: nodes
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - debug:
       msg: "Restarting the service"

   - include: stop.yml

   - include: start.yml
```

The modules you should [use](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#see-also):

- include_tasks
- include

Note that [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#synopsis) should not be used during play execution.

Also, please output the error you're having.